# Remove select options where text is not between two values

Tags: jquery

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>35</option>
</select>
```

I've got the following working code which removes all select options where the option text is less than 5:

```
$("#filter-group5 select option").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) <  5;     
}).remove();
```

How can I modify the code to remove all options that are not between two integers (5,30)?

I tried the following:

```
$("#filter-group5 select option").filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).text()) <  5 && $.trim($(this).text()) >  30;     
}).remove();
```

But it does not work. Nothing happens, all options remain, even those under 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to parse the innerText to Number.
2. Use `||` OR instead of `&&.

**Code:**

```
$("#filter-group5 select option").filter(function(){
    return +$(this).text() <  5 || +$.trim($(this).text() > 30;     
}).remove();
```